# How could i display a Graph on WindowsForms?

Tags: c#, graph, oscilloscope

i am a beginner at c#, so you could help me. At first, i get some data from a RS422 to USB converter over a COM Port and now i want to display over the right COM-Port the graph on the Screen. 
My Question:
How could i display the Graph on my WindowsForms ?

Sorry for my english.

M.Spitz

Answer (score 11):

There is a nice tool in Windows Forms called [Chart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart(v=vs.110).aspx). You can draw graphs of different kind with it.

Here is a [Tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489237.aspx)

Here is a [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=82jnryBxsnI) that shows how to use it.

Here is a nice post with an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622674/chart-creating-dynamically-in-net-c-sharp) from StackOverflow.

Have fun exploring it.

Basically the steps are:

> 1. Create a Series for each line you want to draw.
> 2. Add the values from your array or list to the series.
>
> EDIT: 3. See comment by TaW

EDIT 2) : here you find all different [chart types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489233.aspx) that can be displayed.

and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456769.aspx) how to use them.

When you click in the property window of the chart on `Series` you get the Series-Properties. There you can also find the property: `ChartType` and set it by a mouse click if you want to.

Comment: For an oscillopsope effect step 3 is to remove DataPoints from the Left as new ones are coming in or moving the minimum and maximum vlaues for the x-axis.

Comment: Why not, it will display the point that you feed into it. If you have an array that contains the right values it will display it. See my edit

Comment: At first thank you guys:) Another Question, i hope you can help me also like the first one. How does the Chart knows the right COM-Port? I will give the user a selection of COM-Ports over a Dropdown Menu.

Comment: the Chart won't know anything about a COM Port. It knows only about the numbers that you feed into it. This is your responsibility.

Comment: I wish you success! :)

Comment: Only available up to .NET 4.8. On .NET Core, you'll need to install the package "System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization" (prerelease) - here's the resolved issue page: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/port-the-ms-chart-conmtrol-to-dot-net-core/1116076

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to create the port object and set the necessary parameters for it from the design view
[search for port tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GUDq.png)

or your code like this

```
dataPort.PortName = your_port_name;
dataPort.BaudRate = your_baud_rate;
```

After you open the port and read the data from it:

```
dataPort.Open();

while(dataPort.IsOpen)
{
    chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(val.Second, dataPort.ReadByte());
    chart1.Update();
}
```